# How can I maintain the border-bottom color of a href when I click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my current menu: [image: this is my current menu]

Hello, This is my current menu and the thing I want to do is,
when I click Shop, I want the border-bottom of Shop to be red and maintain the red color until I click the other menus.

This is my source code.

```js
$(".hd_qnb_link").on("click",function(){        
       $(".hd_qnb_link").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
   }       
);
```

```css
.hd_qnb_link {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
.active {border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="hd_qnb">
 <li><a href="#" class="hd_qnb_link">shop</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="hd_qnb_link">about us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="hd_qnb_link">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

but it still does not work. I have been struggling this problem for a day, and finally asking here for some help. Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New information:
Your navigation when clicked is loading a new page. Javascript isn't the answer. CSS is.

For each page you load, put a class in your `<body>` tag. Like for the shop page, put `<body class='shop'>` etc.

Your navigation also needs classes, like

```
<ul id="hd_qnb">
 <li><a href="#" class="shop-link hd_qnb_link">shop</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="about-link hd_qnb_link">about us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="contact-link hd_qnb_link">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Finally, your CSS, something like this:

```
.hd_qnb_link {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
body.shop .hd_qnb_link.shop-link,
body.about .hd_qnb_link.about-link,
body.contact .hd_qnb_link.contact-link {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red; 
}
```

---

Original:
As you see in the snippet below. It does work just fine. What the issue probably is you're running your code before the HTML has a chance to load, so the event listener you have isn't finding anything to listen to when it runs. Try putting that event listener, and any other initialization code inside a `window.onload` function like below:

```
  window.onload = function() {
     $(".hd_qnb_link").on("click", function() {
      $(".hd_qnb_link").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  }
```

```js
$(".hd_qnb_link").on("click", function() {
  $(".hd_qnb_link").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.hd_qnb_link {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="hd_qnb">
  <li><a href="#" class="hd_qnb_link">shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="hd_qnb_link">about us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="hd_qnb_link">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried the solution you've told me but it still does not work.. www.tndtnkr.com this is the website. This makes me so sad

Comment: I see. The problem is the page is refreshing after you click the link. You need a different approach. Event listeners won't work because the page refreshes.

Comment: Can you help me with finding the different approach?? I am not familiar with Javascript, so it would be a huge hint for the problem with your advice!

Comment: with your big help, I have finally solved the problem. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the color of the border bottom in the HTML file of the shop menu.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function()){
$( "li" ).first().css( "border-bottom-color", "red" );
});
</script>
```